# QObject::connection(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) "Cannot convert argument 3 from 'fileProcessor' to const QObject *"

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I need the instance of p to by of type QObject it seems, I have extended QObject and defined the keyword Q_OBJECT in fileprocessor.h, I am not sure what else I can do.

-**Fileprocessor.h**

```
#ifndef FILEPROCESSOR_H
#define FILEPROCESSOR_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QObject>

class fileProcessor: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    fileProcessor();
public slots:
    void on_action_Open_triggered();
    void checkString(QString &temp, QChar ch = 0);

public:
QList<QStringList> csv;
QStandardItemModel *model;
QList<QStandardItem*> standardItemList;
};


#endif // FILEPROCESSOR_H
```

-**Mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "fileProcessor.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    fileProcessor p;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     p,SLOT(on_action_Open_triggered()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

-**Mainwindow.cpp**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();


public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Error:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Assignment3\mainwindow.cpp:10:
>   error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject
>   *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'fileProcessor' to 'const QObject *' No
>   user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the compiler means by this line

> cannot convert argument 3 from 'fileProcessor' to 'const QObject *'

is that you are passing in an object rather than a *pointer* to the object.

So all you need to do is an the ampersand to get a pointer to p, like this, right?

```
fileProcessor p;
ui->setupUi(this);
QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 &p,SLOT(on_action_Open_triggered()));
```

It will compile, but it won't work.

Why?  Your variable p will go out of scope and be destroyed at the end of the constructor, so there's no way it's slot will ever be called.

The most straightforward solution is to declare p as a member variable of your MainWindow class.  That way your fileProcessor will exist as long as its MainWindow exists.

Comment: Great thank you your insight, my train of thought was a little off. after declaring it as a pointer to p, it is now telling me "unresolved external symbols" is this a reflection of the out of scope issue

Comment: There's no reason to *declare* p as a pointer, you just need to take the address of the object with the & operator like I did above.  Unresolved symbols is probably a linker issue and sounds like a new question.

Comment: I just had to run qmake again after doing some googling. Thanks again for taking the time to help :)